# node.js - mocha installation permission denied

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have successfully installed mocha on my linux computer using the command:

`sudo npm install -g mocha`

When I try to use mocha, or simply call it using the command `mocha`,

I get this error:

`/usr/bin/env: node: Permission denied`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My search led me to https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node

The site mentions that the node version should be 0.10.32 and that npm version should be higher than 2.1.8

My local versions were lower, with npm being drastically lower, around 1.3

`sudo apt-get install node` installs an older version of node, so after looking around I found https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions, which appears to install the latest node version.

My npm version was still low after the install so I ran `sudo npm install npm -g`, which finally updated my npm version to 2.5.

After my npm update, mocha works